# Stunnel - how to generate pem file simply on Windows

Tags: windows, certificate, stunnel

Somebody suggest me stunnel. 
We want to use for encrypt requests.

This is seems to be easier than OpenVPN.

The problem that I don't have SSH or other tool in the Windows server, and I don't have any chance to generate pem files for server.

The biggest problem that I must provide some description for other admins to install stunnel server too... But I'm also blocked in this position, and I don't know, how to do the next step...

Is anybody have some idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The new version contains a pem generator.

Comment: So this means you no longer need help? I'm going to close your question - let me know if this isn't the case.